# Doctrine uses old project files proxies

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a big problem on a Symfony 4 Project.

I have this error :

```
Compile Error: Doctrine\\Common\\Proxy\\Autoloader::Doctrine\\Common\\Proxy\\{closure}(): Failed opening required 'C:\\wamp64\\www\\fvpaback\\var\\cache\\dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies\\__CG__TestBundleEntityCommunity.php' (include_path='.;C:\\php\\pear')
```

The problem is that TestBundle is not the project name, but an old project from where the Community come from. I searched in the code and there is not any TestBundle...
Doctrine generates the good filename in the cache **__CG__AppEntityCommunity.php**... but he try to access **__CG__TestBundleEntityCommunity.php**

I don't understand why, and I'm going crazy with it...

Comment: Run `php bin/console cache:clear` and check your AppKernel

Comment: I already done a cache:clear, what I'm supposed to check in AppKernel ?

Comment: Have you tried simple deleting the var/cache folder?

Comment: Yes I tried cache-clear, doctrine:cache:clear-xxxxx, clear cache composer and reinstall packages, another browser,  deleting var/cache, composer dump-autoload

:(

Comment: Did you try to clear doctrine cache?

``php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata``

``php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query``

``php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-result``

Comment: Did you clear your APC cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem came from WAMP, the mysql server keeps some links from the old project, don't know why. Delete the database and create a fresh one solve the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try running `composer run-script post-update-cmd`.

Your `bootstrap.php.cache` will be regenerated and every generated code from previous files will be removed.

Comment: I will try it and keep you informed tonight.
For information, I deployed the project on another fresh linux and everything worked well... I guess that Windows version of PHP installed with WAMP is keeping cache and it's the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same issue happened, an old entity proxy name was encoded in remember_me cookie, that it!

- Examine your cookie for a possible old proxy name
- If found, disable remember_me support in security config to prevent compile error
- Implement a kernel event listener to clear remember_me cookie on response
- Wait for X hours/days/whatever till active user agents invalidate its cookie
- Enable back remember_me support

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please explain in a bit more details to add value in the answer. Elaborate how your answer solves the problem differently than the accepted answer